# Form f.select populate with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to select a number from a list with an incoming parameter but it has no effect when the form is set to f.select.

```
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.select :projectWorth, (0..100).to_a.map{|n| [n, n]}, :value=>params[:projectWorth], label: "Worth"%>
    </div>
```

When I send in the projectWorth parameter it does not set the value.

It works when its an `f.text_field` no problem.

**Solution**

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.select :projectWorth, options_for_select((0..100).to_a.map{|n| [n, n]}, params[:projectWorth]), label: "Worth"%>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `options_for_select(data, selected)`

So in your case it will look like `options_for_select((0..100).to_a.map{|n| [n, n]}, params[:projectWorth])`

Also avoid using camel case for your variables. Instead of `:projectWorth` use `:project_worth`

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you Avdept.